# Nullable int/Int32 in .Net EDMX model?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, edmx

Is it possible to have a properly nullable int in an EDMX model to match the nullable FK int in my Db table?

I will add that there is a problem. I think I figured out HOW to make the int nullable fully, but it FK links to a KEY column in another table in the model, so that is a major problem.

Entlib 4

I have an Entity object like so:

```
    /// <summary>
/// No Metadata Documentation available.
/// </summary>
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="Ideal.TicketCommerce", Name="PAYMENTPLAN")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class PAYMENTPLAN : EntityObject
{
    #region Factory Method
```

And a Property that I want to be nullable from by .Net (C#) code so that I can literally set it to null and pass that to the INSERT EDMX generated statement:

```
        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int32 ORDERPAYMENTID
    {
        get
        {
            return _ORDERPAYMENTID;
        }
        set
        {
            OnORDERPAYMENTIDChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("ORDERPAYMENTID");
            _ORDERPAYMENTID = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("ORDERPAYMENTID");
            OnORDERPAYMENTIDChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.Int32 _ORDERPAYMENTID;
    partial void OnORDERPAYMENTIDChanging(global::System.Int32 value);
    partial void OnORDERPAYMENTIDChanged();
```

Comment: Yes, it is. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I can't figure out how to do it. How is it done? Tried setting Nullable=true, using the old question mark trick. Nothing seems to fly.

Comment: Model first? Database first? What object's properties are you viewing in what window, using which version of Entity Framework? I don't know of a "question mark trick", so you may want to [edit] your question to include the exact steps you've taken and where you're stuck.

Comment: I updated my question. Thanks! This was a model completely generated from a FireBird db.

So, I need to be able to set paymentPlan.ORDERPAYMENTID = null and have that retained and passed as null to the Entlib insert statement for new records added to that table.